# The current status of human genome annotation

Tags: sequence-annotation, human-genome

I was wondering if you can suggest something on the current status of the human genome annotation efforts. I know about ENSEMBL/HAVANA/GENCODE, and I've read the relevant papers; however, I was wondering if RefSeq or UCSC are still actively developed, and are there any competing efforts on T2T assembly, human pan-genome, etc etc?

I know there are quite a few projects that generate both short and long read RNA-seq and other "evidence" from lots of cell lines etc. I guess I was looking for a good and up-to-date perspective or a review type of article.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site @AlexanderPredeus. Thanks for your question, there are a number of different questions here and the format we request is focus on a single issue as the basis of the question. You can always ask multiple questions. What we want to avoid is a discussion forum. Please do consider editing your question.